# tensor product of motivic complexes $\mathbf{Z}(n)$

Tags: motivic-cohomology

Is the morphism $\mathbf{Z}(n) \otimes^L \mathbf{Z}(m) \to \mathbf{Z}(n+m)$ from the Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjectures a quasi-isomorphism?

Comment: you will probably need to give more context in order to receive an answer.

Comment: Being brief: yes, by definition.:)

Comment: See page $6$ of [these notes](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~bloch/talk090108.pdf) and page $80$ of [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=zbEnFYFXL9MC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=tensor+product+of+motivic+complex&source=bl&ots=tuS70YUoBX&sig=APJggIHj6Z02fx22VTERcggx5pE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_c7rU7C0Msv-oQSpx4D4BA&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=tensor%20product%20of%20motivic%20complex&f=false).